# How to use Shift_R+Ctrl_R as a third row modifier?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xkb

I bought a weird keyboard for windozers (Defender Oscar SM-600 PRO). Instead of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, it has a <kbd>LNG</kbd> key, that sends a combination of <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd>, and it does not seem to support rebinding it.

`xev` output when the key is pressed:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 321055557, (664,518), root:(666,520),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 321055557, (664,518), root:(666,520),
    state 0x14, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 321055670, (664,518), root:(666,520),
    state 0x15, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x6cb, subw 0x0, time 321055670, (664,518), root:(666,520),
    state 0x11, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I make <kbd>Shift_R</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd> a third-row modifier, so this key will act as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>? Ideally, it should be also possible to press <kbd>Shift_L</kbd>+<kbd>LNG</kbd> (<kbd>Shift_L</kbd>+<kbd>Shift_R</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd>), to access the fourth row.

Comment: Try to run `xev` (from the console) in any standard Linux distribution and press that `LNG` button. You’ll see what event it sends to the bus. That value(s) might be mapped with `xmodmap` later.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin this is what I already did and how I found out that it sends `Shift_R`+`Ctrl_R`. AFAIK, `xmodmap` is not able to map a combination of keys, so it's unsuitable for this task.

Comment: Would you mind to update the question with a copy-paste of `xev` output? AFAICT, events are serialized; that said, they cannot come simultaneously. Do they come one after another? In what order does `xev` receives their states? Anyway, please copy-paste the outcome of `xev`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin done

Comment: Well, my experiments could not be considered _the same_, but I was kinda able to set modificators for triple keys in `~/.Xmodmap` with `add mod1 = Ctrl_R Shift_R Alt_R` (works for all the three buttons pressed.) I hope it would work with your «two-in-one” button as well, since it just emulates two events.

Comment: What is funny, that `LNG` sends keyup in the very same order as keydown :) I nearly broke my fingers trying to reproduce that behavior.